# Get documents names in Firestore

Tags: firebase, angularfire2, google-cloud-firestore

When I get several documents from a collection, the result is only an array with each doc data.

```
firestore.collection("categories").valueChanges().subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data);
    // result will be: [{…}, {…}, {…}]
};
```

---

How can I get the name of each doc?

The ideal result would look like this:

```
{"docname1": {…}, "docname2": {…}, "docname3": {…}}
```

Comment: you need to use `snapshotChanges()`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
// Print each document 
db.collection("categories")
    .onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            console.log(doc.data()); // For data inside doc
            console.log(doc.id); // For doc name
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

When you need to access additional metadata like the key of your Document, you can use the `snapshotChanges()` streaming method.

```
firestore.collection("categories").valueChanges().map(document => {
      return document(a => {
        const data = a.payload.doc.data();//Here is your content
        const id = a.payload.doc.id;//Here is the key of your document
        return { id, ...data };
      });
```

You can review the [documentation](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/firestore/collections.md) for further explanation and example

Comment: Firestore syntax has changed since posting this answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is dart code:

```
child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('your collection')
          .snapshots(), // path to collection of documents that is listened to as a stream
      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
        return ListView(
          children: snapshot.data.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot doc) { // get document data
            return yourWidget( // return a widget for every document in the collection
               docId: doc.id // get document name
            );
          }).toList(), // casts to list for passing to children parameter
        );
      },
    ),
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It may be a good idea to add a bit of explanation to the code, i. e. why or how it solves the problem, so that others can learn from the answer.