# Angular Firestore Query cannot get id of document

Tags: javascript, angular, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

im querying data in my angular webapp like this:

```
this.notesCollection = this.afs.collection('BasicBlogs', ref =>{
    return ref.where('title','==', blog)
  });
  this.notes = this.notesCollection.valueChanges()
```

and here is my Note:

```
interface Note{
imageUrl: string;
title: string;
body: string;
titledesc: string;
imgalt: string;
imgdesc: string;
imgtitle: string;
authorId: string;
state: string;

}
```

the problem now is that i cannot access the document id of each document which passes the query params. Therefore i tried the following but it didnt work:

```
 this.notesCollection = this.afs.collection('BasicBlogs', ref =>{
  return ref.where('title','==', blog)
 });
  this.notes = this.notesCollection.valueChanges()
  this.id = this.notesCollection.valueChanges.id
```

Comment: The `valueChanges` stream only shows the values, which does not include the document IDs. If you want to get the document ID, observe `documentChanges()` instead of `valueChanges()`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47953387/get-documents-names-in-firestore/47989816#47989816

Comment: thanks you solved my problem