# Get documents name in Firestore and create nested object

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

This question is related to this one: [Get documents names in Firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47953387/get-documents-names-in-firestore) but I can't comment yet.

I am trying to get a nested object from my FireStore which looks like this

```
{"docname1": {…}, "docname2": {…}, "docname3": {…}}
```

I have this now but cant seem to figure out how to create the nested object to push it into the empty array.

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const getPlants = async () => {
        let response = []
        const querySnapshot = await firebase
            .firestore()
            .collection('plants')
            .get()
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            let newObject = [doc.id: doc.data() ]
            response.push(newObject)
        })

        setPlants(response)
    }
    getPlants()
}, [])
```

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are creating the new object (newObject) wrong. Try to create it like this:

```js
   querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
       const newObject = {}
       newObject[doc.id] = doc.data()
       response.push(newObject)
   })
```

Or, you can do this:

```js
   querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
       response.push({ [`${doc.id}`]: doc.data() })
   })
```

Comment: I was struggling with the object creation but this works like a charm. Thanks so much for your help :) .

Comment: The next issue arises; mapping over nested arrays. I ve created this sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/spring-fast-w0tt4?file=/src/App.js  any clue how to get the names displayed?